# auto_append_file giving error (internal server error)

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am appending two files in my .htaccess file and write these lines:

```
php_value auto_append_file begin_caching.php
php_value auto_append_file end_caching.php
```

But it giving me internal server error.

Comment: check the server log for actual error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of web hosts prohibit you using `auto_prepend_file` in .htaccess as a security measure, so this is probably why you're running into the 500 server error.

Why don't you just use this in your PHP file(s):

```
include 'begin_caching.php';

// Main PHP content

include 'end_caching.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative using .htaccess files is using `AddHandler`

.htaccess

```
AddHandler phptemplate .htm
AddHandler phptemplate .html
Action phptemplate /template.php
```

template.php

```
<?php

if (!isset($_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO']))
    die('Error.');

readfile(ltrim($_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO'], '/'));

?>
```